# How do you create a scrollview in kivy python with for loop and have each button their own function parameter

Tags: python, button, kivy

So I am trying to create a program where you click on a button and it gives you a random task from a list of tasks you provide and another button to list all those tasks. So there is no errors in the code, the only problem is that when I run it, I want each button to call the same function but give different parameters depending on the i variable in the loop. Also I took out the button that gets the task since that is not in any way related to the problem.

GUI code:

```
#imports
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
import Functions
import sys
import time



class Home(FloatLayout):
#function that setups the first page
    def setup(self, obj):
        self.clear_widgets()

        List = Button(
        text="Your List",
        font_size=20,
        size_hint=(1/6, 1/12),
        pos_hint={"x":2.5/6, "y":1/6},
        on_press = self.LIISST
        )




        self.add_widget(List)



#function that lists tasks
    def LIISST(self, obj):
        self.clear_widgets()
        FUNC_ = Functions.Choose_("GE", 5)
        FUNC_.sort()

        LT = GridLayout(
        cols=1,
        spacing=10,
        size_hint_y=None,
        )
        LT.bind(minimum_height=LT.setter('height'))

        SCR = ScrollView(
        size_hint=(1/3.5, 2/3),
        pos=(self.width*137/384, self.height/3.25)
        )



        for i in range(len(FUNC_)):
            but_ = Button(text=str(FUNC_[i]),
            size_hint=(18/20, None),
            height=40,
            font_size=self.width/75,
            on_press=lambda s:Functions.Choose_("DE", but_.text)
            )

            LT.add_widget(but_)
        SCR.add_widget(LT)



        ACC_ = Button(
        text="Back",
        font_size=20,
        size_hint=(1/8, 1/14),
        pos_hint={"x":3.5/8, "y":1/6},
        on_press=self.setup
        )


        self.add_widget(SCR)
        self.add_widget(ACC_)



    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Home, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.clearcolor = (255/255, 255/255, 255/255, 255/255)



        self.setup(self)



class App_(App):

    def build(root):
        return Home()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    App_().run()
```

Function to get the task: (separate file)

```
import random
import sys

def Choose_(vall_, VAAL_):
    try:

        #variables
        cfile = open(r"Choice.txt", "r+")
        cfile.seek(0)
        dfile = open(r"Done.txt", "r+")
        dfile.seek(0)
        items = []
        DON = []

        #appenders for items in file to line
        [items.append(line) for line in cfile]
        [DON.append(line) for line in dfile]

        stripp1 = [s.strip() for s in items]
        stripp2 = [s.strip() for s in DON]

        stripp1.sort()
        stripp2.sort()

        if vall_ == "DE":
            print(VAAL_)

        if vall_ == "GE":
            return stripp1
            sys.exit()

        for s in stripp2:
            if s in stripp1:
                stripp1.remove(s)

        if not stripp1:
            dfile.seek(0)
            dfile.truncate(0)
            return False
            sys.exit()


        luck = random.randint(0, (len(stripp1)-1))

        dfile.write(stripp1[luck])
        dfile.write("\n")

        return(stripp1[luck])
    finally:
        cfile.close()
        dfile.close()
```

Task file (same directory as above codes):

```
ClIP STUDIO PAINT
CYBRARY (HACKING)
CYBRARY (LINUX)
VIRTUAL DJ
RASPBERRY PI
PACKET TRACER
VIRTUALBOX
PHOTOSHOP
BLENDER
SOLIDWORKS
KHAN ACADEMY (ANATOMY)
SOLOLEARN
UNITY
KHAN ACADEMY (ELECTRICAL)
PROGRAMMING
KHAN ACADEMY (PHYSICS)
ADOBE PREMIERE
```

Tasks already done(again, same directory as above files):

```
ClIP STUDIO PAINT
CYBRARY (HACKING)
CYBRARY (LINUX)
VIRTUAL DJ
RASPBERRY PI
PACKET TRACER
```

I expected the output to print the button's text for each different button, but it only texts the very last item in the task file for each button, which is virtualbox. Also the code sorts the tasks in abc order, which is why the last item is virtualbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

> I expected the output to print the button's text for each different
>   button, but it only texts the very last item in the task file for each
>   button, which is virtualbox.
>
> I want each button to call the same function but give different
>   parameters depending on the i variable in the loop.

## Root Cause

The text printed is always "VIRTUALBOX" because it is the last button added and it is referenced in the call by `but_.text`.

## Solution

The following enhancements are required to solve the problem.

### main.py

- Implement a new method, `callback()`
- Bind button's `on_press` event to the new method, `callback()`

#### Snippets - main.py

```
    for i in range(len(FUNC_)):
        but_ = Button(text=str(FUNC_[i]),
                      size_hint=(18 / 20, None),
                      height=40,
                      font_size=self.width / 75,
                      on_press=self.callback
                      )

        LT.add_widget(but_)
    SCR.add_widget(LT)
    ...

def callback(self, instance):
    print(f"\ncallback: instance={instance}, text={instance.text}")
    Functions.Choose_("DE", instance.text)
```

### Output

[image: Result - Clicked Button RASPBERRYPI]

Comment: Thank you very much now the program works perfectly you do not understand how much I needed this. Thank you very much my bro.

Comment: [If you want to say "thank you", vote on or accept that person's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

[If you accept someone else's answer: You gain +2 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: I just did. Thank you very much